# Limit of a particular sum of reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let it be the infinite set of positive integers $S=\{{a_1,a_2,...}\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=\lfloor{n^2\ln\left({n}\right)}\rfloor$. Does the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_i}$ converge or diverge? And if it converges, to which limit?

I find interesting this series in particular because the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_i}$ of reciprocals of prime numbers diverges at a rate of aproximately $\ln\ln\left({n}\right)$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i\approx\frac{1}{2}n^2\ln\left({n}\right)$. Therefore, if the series proposed diverges, it is expected to do so at a very slow divergence rate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In fact hard to believe that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, even more surprising is that the sum is still diverging if we only sum over the primes of the form $an+b$ where $a,b$ are coprime positive integers and $n$ runs over the postive integers.

Comment: @Peter, really interesting comment! I will look for info about it ;)

Comment: This is the stronger version of Dirichlet's theorem , we not only have infinite many primes of the form $an+b$ , if $a,b$ are coprime, the sum of the reciprocals is even diverging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $a_n=[n^{2} \ln (n)]-[(n-1)^{2}\ln (n-1)] \leq n^{2} \ln (n)+1-(n-1)^{2}\ln (n-1)$. Now $n^{2} \ln (n)-n^{2} \ln (n-1)=n^{2}\ln (1+\frac 1  {n-1})\leq \frac {n^{2}} {n-1}$. Now you can easily see that $a_n =O(n \ln (n))$. Since $\sum \frac  1 {n \ln (n)}$ is divergent it follows that $\sum \frac 1 {a_n}=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer @KaviRamaMurthy!

Comment: I think you made a typo - is that supposed to be $a_n = O(n\ln(n))$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Yes, thank you for the comment.